# OpenLdap, добавление схемы Samba и распространение ее на определенного пользователя

Tags: администрирование, samba, ldap, centos7

Описание: Есть сервер centos 7.4  на нем установлен openldap 2.4.44, добавлены схемы :

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /home/chrootpw.ldif 
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.ldif
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif
```

согласно одному из множества руководств в интернете завел админа (имя учетки Manager), добавил домен test.rdi и завел в нем учетную запись пользователя p_morozov в группе People. 
Вопрос как добавить схему samba содержащую поля sambaLMPassword и sambaNTPassword, распространить ее на пользователя p_morozov и заполнить ранее указанные поля заранее сгенерированными хешами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идем на сервер, где установлена `Samba`, и в каталоге `/usr/share/doc/samba-X.Y.Z` ищем файл `samba.schema` (X.Y.Z - версия Самбы). Например, каталог в котором может лежать нужный файл, может называться так: `/usr/share/doc/samba-4.6.2/LDAP`

Далее, копируем файл `samba.schema` на сервер, где установлен `OpenLDAP` и кладем его в папку `/etc/openldap/schema`

Далее, добавляем в конфиг файл `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf` строку:

```
include /etc/openldap/schema/samba.schema
```

и делаем рестарт `openldap`:

```
systemctl restart slapd.service
```

После этого `OpenLDAP` сервер "знает" про `objectClass` `sambaSamAccount`.

Этот objectClass содержит атрибуты `sambaLMPassword` и `sambaNTPassword`, которые будет использовать Самба (про атрибуты `NThash` и `LMhash` лично я никогда не слышал).

Далее, редактируем нужную учетную запись (p_morozov) "расширяя" список objectClass-ов для нее. Т.е. как минимум нужно расширить классом  `sambaSamAccount`. После чего можно будет добавить нужные данные в необходимые атрибуты.

Как это сделать из командной строки - не подскажу, т.к. очень редко такое делаю, а с LDAP-сервером работаю через `LDAP Admin` или любую подобную программу.

**PS**
Это очень краткая инструкция к действию. А на самом деле может возникнуть множество проблем, которые не позволят быстро достичь необходимого результата. Вплоть до того, что вам придется пересоздавать данного пользователя средствами Самбы (что вообще говоря более правильно), т.к. есть еще один обязательный атрибут помимо `uid` - `sambaSID`.

Comment: Немного поясню, я пишу скрипт добавления пользователей и если не сильно сложно, мне бы получить пример ldif файла с необходимым минимумом для добавления пользователя со схемой samba (поля sambaLMPassword  и sambaNTPassword) и краткими пояснениями от чего зависит sambaSid и как его правильно изменить для добавления следующего пользователя.

Comment: @Андрей я правильно понимаю, что данный LDAP не является бэкэндом Самбы (контроллера домена)? А вам всего лишь надо заполненнить атрибуты sambaLMPassword и sambaNTPassword какими-то занчениями?

Comment: именно , схему я уже добавил но нарвался как раз sambasid, в принципе поставить самбу можно, для получения каких либо скриптов но использовать лдап бекендом не хотелось бы так как начальство скорее будет против, поэтому хотелось бы как раз использовать ldap с добавленной схемой ито не на всех пользователей

Comment: @Андрей ну, в таком случае поле `sambaSid` можно заполнять (я так думаю) какой-нибудь строковой байдой (т.к. оно имеет тип `Text`). Если бы это был бэкэнд контроллера домена, то строка могла выглядеть как `S-1-5-21-980748733-179848368-1815428657-9630`. А в вашем случае оно попросту не используется.  Либо отредактировать саму схему, сделав это поле необязательным - тогда его не надо инициализировать. Тут уж сами решайте как делать.

Comment: А можно подробней именно как отредактировать схему? я  посмотрел ее(mcedit /etc/openldap/schema/samba.schema ), неувидел параметр отвечающий за обязательнгость.

Comment: @Андрей ищите в этом файле строку `objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.7165.2.2.6 NAME 'sambaSamAccount'`, двумя строчками ниже `MUST ( uid $ sambaSID ) `, превращаете ее в строку `MUST ( uid ) `, а параметр `sambaSID ` "переносите" в строку ниже `MAY  ( cn $ sambaLMPassword $ sambaNTPassword $ sambaPwdLastSet $`. Добавьте его в любое место этого списка, разделитель атрибутов - знак `$`

Comment: Не знаю почему но в моем случае не было slapd.conf, я использовал ldapmodify и samba.ldif (но кстати samba schema на всякий тоже отредактировал) , а перед этим в samba.ldif убрал sambasid из must в разедле SambaSamAccount  и все срботало.

Comment: @Андрей в вашем случае `slapd` пользовался конфигурацией из каталога `/etc/openldap/slapd.d` и используя `olc` (on-line configuration) параметры. Этот способ начал использоваться с версии 2.3. Но я по старинке использую slapd.conf.

Comment: все равно спасибо , помогло